# JSP: Format date as "yyyy-MM-dd h:mm a" within a <form:input> field for datetimepicker

Tags: java, jquery, jstl

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3">
    <label for="appointment_date" class="required" style="margin-left:30px">Appointment Date: <span class="blue">*</span></label>
    <input id="appointment_date" name="appointment_date" type="text" class="form-control" data-datetimepicker="" required style="margin-left:30px;width: 190px;">
</div>
```

modified.js pages as below

```
$('#appointment_date').datetimepicker({
                controlType: 'select',
                oneLine: true,
                timeFormat: 'hh:mm TT',
                showSecond: false,
                showMillisec: false,
                showMicrosec: false,
                showTimezone: false
            });
```

Can some help me to get Date in the pattern of "yyyy-MM-dd h:mm a"?

I tried below methods but did not worked:

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3">
     <label for="appointment_date" class="required" style="margin-left:30px">Appointment Date: <span class="blue">*</span></label>
     <fmt:formatDate pattern="yyyy-MM-dd h:mm a"  type="date"  value="${appointment_date}" var="FormattedDate"/>
     <input id="appointment_date" name="appointment_date" type="text" class="form-control" data-datetimepicker="" required value="${FormattedDate}" style="width: 190px;">
</div>
```